# Create custom domain in localhost which all local users can access (LINUX)

Tags: linux, dns, ip

I want to create a custom domain name which will run on my IP

If i host a web server then if someone view 'mylocalsite.com' , then my ip web server will be shown

For Example:

My IP: `192.168.1.111`

Domain: `mylocalsite.com`

Show my IP response in mylocalsite.com, We are talkin about **LINUX**

Is that Possible in anyway?

Comment: Where are your users located? in the same LAN, on the same machine, or across the Internet?

Comment: You need to create a record in `/etc/hosts` if you only want to allow local machine to access your site. You need to create a record on your router if you want to allow users in the same LAN to access. You need to purchase a domain if you want to allow Internet to access.

Comment: if your users are on the same LAN networks as your webserver then you can do that by configuring the your router settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***IF USERS ARE WINDOWS Not Recommend***

Edit the c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts file on each users machine and point those names to 192.168.1.111.

192.168.1.111 mylocalsite.com

***Another solution***

host your own local DNS server and bind your IP address to the URL.

Comment: No I didnt it was same, btw i know where linux hosts file are stored /etc/hosts

Answer (score 2):

### Recommended solution: Configure the router

Modify the configuration of your router. Most router should support `custom DNS record`, `custom domain` or something like this.

For linux-based routers such as OpenWRT and DDWRT, you can directly modify the  `/etc/hosts` of the router, or modify the argument of dnsmasq.

### Unrecommended solution: Configure every client

- If the client is on Windows

Please refer to @S.Sachith's answer. (Modify `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`)

- If the client is on Linux/MacOS/BSD

Please modify `/etc/hosts` to add the custom DNS record. Use google to find out the detailed syntax.

- If the client is on Android/iOS

Search for `hosts modifier`, `hosts go`, or some app like this, to modify the DNS record. You can also directly modify `/system/etc/hosts` by hand if you have root access.